# how can I let tomcat look in another ROOT folder

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible for me to start my web application from somewhere else than the ROOT folder in tomcat? I've build my app in eclipse, and this is the structure

```
web
    WEB-INF
        build
            mypackage 
                HomeServlet.class
        web.xml 
    home.jsp
```

would it be possible for me to just run tomcat from the tomcat folder, and have this app run at localhost/app?

NOTE: I'm not looking to run tomcat through my IDE. I know that it's possible, but I looking to run tomcat as a standalone application

Comment: A way to do this would be a redirect. Redirect from localhost/app to the required folder

Comment: How is this structure any different from the one you told me yesterday?

Comment: The directory containing the classes must be named `classes`. Not `build`.

Comment: Ah ok that explains a lot. Do I have to name it com aswell? And do I have to have 2 folders and then my .class files?

Comment: Under the classes directory, you must have a directory hierarchy that is the same as the package hierarachy (as always in Java). If the Servlet class is in package `com.foo.bar`, then its class file must be in `WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar`.

Comment: Should I also do servlet mapping in my web.xml, or is it also okay to do like @WebServlet(name="Home", urlPatterns="/home") ? Because I've created the structure just like you said, and copied it to the ROOT folder within tomcat, went to localhost:8080/app and got a 404 :(

Comment: No, the mapping using annotations is sufficient. The servlet is mapped to /home, and it's part of the root webapp, so its path is  `http://localhost:8080/home`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21688/discussion-between-moose-moose-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the path to your `web.xml` like this

```
<Context path="/" docBase="/your/absolute/document/root" />
```

More details on the context container you find [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)